# Google OAuth flow. "Request had invalid authentication credentials"

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0

I have a react-native project using [react-native-google-signIn](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin) where I'm able to get the user's idToken and accessToken.

I need the app to call my .NET backend and have the server make requests to google drive api on behalf of the user.

Here are my credentials in the google console. The OAuth client is for the react-native project and the service account is for the .NET backend. [image]

I'm getting authentication errors when trying to call google drive api. I'm simply setting the request.AccessToken to the accessToken retrieved by react-native-google-sign in. Both the react-native app and .NET backend have credentials in the google console. Any help would be appreciated. [image]